# Does Windows Remote Desktop lock or hide the screen of the remote PC?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

If I connect to my work PC from home, will the screen on the work PC show exactly what I'm doing?  Or, will the screen be blanked and/or locked?  When I log off or disconnect, will my work PC be left unlocked?

Both PCs run Windows 7.

Also, what happens if someone else is already logged in on my work PC when I connect remotely?  Can more than one person be simultaneously logged on?

I can't test this since I only have 2 PCs, and they're not at the same location.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The screen is locked and it will show who is logged in remotely, as well as the hostname of the remote computer. When you log off it remains at the logon screen. More than one person cannot be logged in simultaneously.

> I can't test this since I only have 2
>   PCs, and they're not at the same
>   location.

You can, use VNC.

eg.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand -- how exactly would I use VNC?

Comment: You can use it alongside remote desktop. It will show you the screen from the perspective of the physical monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The default settings mean that the other user will be logged out when you log in. The only way to get around this is to patch the termsrv.dll. As this is a work computer, it is unlikely this will be done, but you can ask your administrator(s). The appropriate file is called "Windows 7 Terminal Server Multiple user patch." I have successfully used this on my home computer.

If your computer used Windows Server 2008, then both users could be logged in at once. You may also want to ask your administrator(s) about that.