# How do I keep the monitors on while connecting through remote desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a computer connected to a projector. That I want to control remotely using RDP and project in the projector it has. Unfortunately, when I use remote desktop, it stops the monitors and projectors.

Is there a way to keep the projector on while being connected through the remote desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand the question, what you want here is [VNC](https://www.tightvnc.com/) and not RDC.  It can be configured to run as a service at boot OR run under the context of a user.

VNC is NOT as performant nor as secure as RDC but it will do exactly what you request here and it is performant and secure enough.

Note that there are 100% free versions of this.  Don't pay for it unless one of the paid versions has something you need that the free versions don't.

Answer (score -1):

With RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) there is no way to do it, you can do it it with other programs used to log in remotely.
see here.
[Does Windows Remote Desktop lock or hide the screen of the remote PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/200415/does-windows-remote-desktop-lock-or-hide-the-screen-of-the-remote-pc)

Comment: How the heck does that other linked question answer this question? I looked it over a few times, and it appears to not add anything new let alone answer the question.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 The question was "I have a computer connected to a projector. That I want to control remotely using RDP" my understanding is that he have a pc let's say it's in a conference room, and he wants to connect to that computer from somewhere else trough RDP and it should be visible the screen for those sitting in the conference room, which i replied that that is impossible.